# Go WaitGroup with goroutine

Tags: go, synchronization, goroutine

I wonder why we need to run the `wg.Wait()` in `goroutine`

```
// This one works as expected...
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
        }()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
    }()
}
```

But this one never ends waiting forever

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
        }()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Can anybody explain why I need to wait in another goroutine?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? I'd guess something is broken in the not shown part of the code, especially as the first version doesn't wait IMHO.

Comment: My code actually does a lot more, which uses its own goroutines again. I get this pattern from https://github.com/rakyll/coop/blob/master/coop.go#L85

Comment: Here, she does `wg.Wait()` in goroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we need to run the `wg.Wait()` in goroutine?

In the example you mention ([`coop/blob/master/coop.go#L85`](https://github.com/rakyll/coop/blob/master/coop.go#L85)), the wait is in a goroutine in order to return immediately a channel that will indicate when all the other goroutines have completed.
Those are the goroutines to be started:

```
for _, fn := range fns {
    go func(f func()) {
        f()
        wg.Done()
    }(fn)
}
```

They mention the completion through the `var wg sync.WaitGroup`.
That WaitGroup is set to wait for the right number of goroutines to finish:

```
wg.Add(len(fns))
```

The wait is done in a goroutine because it will in turn signal the global completion to a channel:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    doneSig(ch, true)
}()
```

But the channel is returned immediately.

```
ch := make(chan bool, 1)
...
return ch
```

That is why the Wait is done asynchronously: you don't want to wait in this function. You just want the channel.